# failsafe plugin does not pick the test classes even though I have the correct naming convention *IT.java

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have searched on the internet as well, but I could not find the exact problem that I am having.

TO explain what I am doing, I am writing selenium UI tests. I am trying to execute the test using the failsafe plugin. I am executing the maven command `mvn clean verify` but it does not execute any of my test classes.

However, my test classes are getting executed when I change my test class to *Test.java

I suspect that my project does not use failsafe instead uses surefire. I am posting my pom file, project structure and the build output.

[image]

**POM File**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>webproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>webproject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>webproject</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
      <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
      <version>3.13.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.14.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>   

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
         <!--see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging-->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20.0</version>
          <configuration>
            <suiteXmlFiles>
              <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng/SampleSuiteIT.xml</suiteXmlFile>
              </suiteXmlFiles>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>integration-test</goal>
                <goal>verify</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: You have to move the maven-failsafe-plugin configuration out of `<pluginManagement>..</pluginManagement> `

Comment: @khmarbaise many thanks. your solution resolved my issue. I was so annoyed with this. Can you add this as an answer so I can select this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move the maven-failsafe-plugin configuration out of `<pluginManagement>..</pluginManagement>`